# PHP equivalent of Java MessageDigest MD5

Tags: java, php, hash, md5

I have this method below in java and need the exact equivalent in PHP as both hashes are being compared..

The Java Method Is:

```
public String getMD5(String inStr)
{
    MessageDigest md5 = null;
    try {
        md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    char[] charArray = inStr.toCharArray();
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[charArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++)
        byteArray[i] = (byte) charArray[i];
        byte[] md5Bytes = md5.digest(byteArray);
        StringBuffer hexValue = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < md5Bytes.length; i++) {
            int val = ((int) md5Bytes[i]) & 0xff;
            if (val < 16)
                hexValue.append("0");
                hexValue.append(Integer.toHexString(val));
            }
            return hexValue.toString();
    }
```

I am currently using the crypt method for php.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Is this not working for you?

```
$str = 'apple';
$hash = md5($str);
```

This would generate a md5 hash in php. Are the output of both functions not equal?